# Python Drawing a tic tac toe board

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I am trying to draw a fake 3x3 tic tac toe board. I am new to python and I don't understand why this does not work. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
def draw():
    for i in range(4):
        board = (" ___ " * 3)

    for i in board:
        ("|    " * 4).join(board)

    print(board)


draw()
```

EDIT:

Final code:

```
def draw():
    board = ''

    for i in range(-1,6):

        if i%2==0:
            board += '|      ' * 4
            board += '\n|      |      |      |'

        else:
            board += ' _____ ' * 3

        board += '\n'
    print (board)

draw()
```

output:

```
 _____  _____  _____ 
|      |      |      |      
|      |      |      |
 _____  _____  _____ 
|      |      |      |      
|      |      |      |
 _____  _____  _____ 
|      |      |      |      
|      |      |      |
 _____  _____  _____
```

Double Edit:

Another way:

```
def drawsmall():
    a = (' ___' *  3 )
    b = '   '.join('||||')
    print('\n'.join((a, b, a, b, a, b, a, )))

drawsmall()
```

output:

```
 ___ ___ ___
|   |   |   |
 ___ ___ ___
|   |   |   |
 ___ ___ ___
|   |   |   |
 ___ ___ ___
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it easier to do this in one loop, printing a row of the board each iteration. You can alternate between vertical and horizontal bars by checking if the current iteration is an even or odd number using the `%` operator.

With strings you don't need to use join -- it can be more clear to append with the `+=` operator.

```
def draw():
    # initialize an empty board
    board = ""

    # there are 5 rows in a standard tic-tac-toe board
    for i in range(5):
        # switch between printing vertical and horizontal bars
        if i%2 == 0:
            board += "|    " * 4
        else:
            board += " --- " * 3
        # don't forget to start a new line after each row using "\n"
        board += "\n"

    print(board)

draw()
```

Output:

```
|    |    |    |    
 ---  ---  --- 
|    |    |    |    
 ---  ---  --- 
|    |    |    |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use variables/functions/loops and want a simple one-liner solution based on Print command:

```
print("__|__|__", "__|__|__", "  |  |  ", sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
def draw():
    a=('\n _____  _____  _____ ')
    b= ('\n|     |      |      |')
    print(a,b,b,a,b,b,a,b,b,a)
draw()
```

Output:

```
 _____  _____  _____  
|     |      |      | 
|     |      |      | 
 _____  _____  _____  
|     |      |      | 
|     |      |      | 
 _____  _____  _____  
|     |      |      | 
|     |      |      | 
 _____  _____  _____
```

for Better view use:

```
def print_tic_tac_toe():
    print("\n")
    print("\t     |     |")
    print("\t     |     |  ")
    print('\t_____|_____|_____')
 
    print("\t     |     |")
    print("\t     |     |  ")
    print('\t_____|_____|_____')
 
    print("\t     |     |")
 
    print("\t     |     |  ")
    print("\t     |     |")
    print("\n")
print_tic_tac_toe()
```

Output :

```
         |     |
         |     |  
    _____|_____|_____
         |     |
         |     |  
    _____|_____|_____
         |     |
         |     |  
         |     |
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up how the `join` function works.  First, it takes the given string and uses that for the "glue", the string that connects the others.  Second, it *returns* the constructed string; your `join` operation fails to save the result.

Try doing this first with nested loops: print a row of boxes, then the horizontal divider, etc.  Then, bit by bit, convert that to the single-string output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def draw():
   return [["__" for b in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
```

Now you have a list of lists which contains your board. To print it out, you can do this:

```
the_board = draw()

for i in the_board:
    for b in i:

        print('|'.join(i), end="") 

    print()

print("  |    |  ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd simplify things so that I could understand it myself. This code produces the same output as above:

```
def draw_board():
    v = '|    |    |    |'
    h = ' ____ ____ ____ '
    for i in range(0,10):
        if i%3==0:
            print(h)
        else:
            print(v)
draw_board()
```

Output:

```
 ____ ____ ____ 
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
 ____ ____ ____ 
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
 ____ ____ ____ 
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
 ____ ____ ____
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
find below python code for end-to-end interactive Tic-Tac-Toe board game.
Code looks lengthy which can be optimized, but it works perfect as interactive Tic-Tac-Toe board game.

```
#Function code to clear the output space (screen)
 
 from IPython.display import clear_output

#code to display just board-

def ttt_borad(board):
cl = clear_output()
print('Your Tic-Tac-Toe board now:\n')
print(board[1] + "|" + board[2] + "|" + board[3])
print("________")
print(board[4] + "|" + board[5] + "|" + board[6])
print("________")
print(board[7] + "|" + board[8] + "|" + board[9])

#function code to accept player key choices-

def player_key():
player_choice = ''
play1 = ''
play2 = ''
while player_choice not in ('Y', 'N'):
    player_choice = input("Player-1 would like to go first ? Enter Y/N: ")
    player_choice = player_choice.upper()
    if player_choice not in ('Y', 'N'):
        print("Invalid Key")
    else:
        pass
if player_choice == 'Y':

    while play1 not in ('X', 'O'):
        play1 = input("Select your Key for Player-1 X or O: ")
        play1 = play1.upper()
        if play1 not in ('X', 'O'):
            print("Invalid Key")
        else:
            pass
else:
    while play2 not in ('X', 'O'):
        play2 = input("Select your Key for Player-2 X or O: ")
        play2 = play2.upper()
        if play2 not in ('X', 'O'):
            print("Invalid Key")
        else:
            pass

if play1 == 'X':
    play2 = 'O'
elif play1 == 'O':
    play2 = 'X'
elif play2 == 'X':
    play1 = 'O'
elif play2 == 'O':
    play1 = 'X'

print(f'Key for Player-1 is: {play1} and Key for Player-2 is: {play2}')
return play1, play2



#function code to accept key strokes to play game

def enter_key(key, bp):
play1, play2 = key
ind = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
i = 1
while i < 10:
    j = 0
    k = 0
    print(f'Game Move: {i}')
    while j not in ind:
        j = input("Player-1: Select position (1-9) for your Move: ")
        if j not in ind:
            print("Invalid Key or Position already marked")
        else:
            pass
    x = ind.index(j)
    ind.pop(x)
    j = int(j)
    bp[j] = play1
    ttt_borad(bp)
    i = i + 1
    tf = game_winner(key, bp)
    if tf == 1:
        print("The Winner is: Player-1 !!")
        break
    print(f'Game Move: {i}')
    if i == 10:
        break

    while k not in ind:
        k = input("Player-2: Select position (1-9) for your Move: ")
        if k not in ind:
            print("Invalid Key or Position already marked")
        else:
            pass
    y = ind.index(k)
    ind.pop(y)
    k = int(k)
    bp[k] = play2
    ttt_borad(bp)
    i = i + 1
    ft = game_winner(key, bp)
    if ft == 2:
        print("The Winner is: Player-2 !!")
        break
return bp

#function code to calculate and display winner of the game-
def game_winner(key, game):
p1, p2 = key
p = 0
if game[1] == game[2] == game[3] == p1:
    p = 1
    return p
elif game[1] == game[4] == game[7] == p1:
    p = 1
    return p
elif game[1] == game[5] == game[9] == p1:
    p = 1
    return p
elif game[2] == game[5] == game[8] == p1:
    p = 1
    return p
elif game[3] == game[6] == game[9] == p1:
    p = 1
    return p
elif game[4] == game[5] == game[6] == p1:
    p = 1
    return p
elif game[3] == game[5] == game[7] == p1:
    p = 1
    return p
elif game[1] == game[2] == game[3] == p2:
    p = 2
    return p
elif game[1] == game[4] == game[7] == p2:
    p = 2
    return p
elif game[1] == game[5] == game[9] == p2:
    p = 2
    return p
elif game[2] == game[5] == game[8] == p2:
    p = 2
    return p
elif game[3] == game[6] == game[9] == p2:
    p = 2
    return p
elif game[4] == game[5] == game[6] == p2:
    p = 2
    return p
elif game[3] == game[5] == game[7] == p2:
    p = 2
    return p
else:
    p = 3
    return p

#Function code to call all functions in order to start and play game-

def game_play():
clear_output()
entry = ['M', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
ttt_borad(entry)
plk = player_key()
new_board = enter_key(plk, entry)
tie = game_winner(plk, new_board)
if tie == 3:
    print("Game Tie !!! :-( ")

print('Would you like to play again? ')
pa = input("Enter Y to continue OR Enter any other key to exit game: ")
pa = pa.upper()
if pa == 'Y':
    game_play()
else:
    pass

game_play()
```

#Try this entire code in any Python3 editor and let me know your feedback.
I have attached sample board how code displays.[Sample Tic-Tac-Toe board by code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODkPW.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_board():
    board_size = int(input("What size game board they want to draw? "))

    horizontal = " ---"
    vertical = "|  "

    for i in range(board_size):
        print(horizontal * board_size)
        print(vertical * (board_size + 1))
    return print(horizontal * board_size)


create_board()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).