# Create a 3x3 grid

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and I want to create a printable `3x3 grid` to represent a Tic-Tac-Toe board. I just want ideas to tidy it up and make the code look better many thanks

```
def display_board(board):
    print('   |     |  ')
    print(board[7] + '  |  ' + board[8] + '  |  ' + board[9])
    print('   |     |  ')
    print('---- ---- ----')
    print('   |     |  ')
    print(board[4] + '  |  ' + board[5] + '  |  ' + board[6])
    print('   |     |  ')
    print('---- ---- ----')
    print('   |     |  ')
    print(board[1] + '  |  ' + board[2] + '  |  ' + board[3])
    print('   |     |  ')
```

This function does create the desired result but I want ideas of how to tidy it up. I've tried `for` loops but it ends up breaking.

Comment: select code and use button `{}` to format it.

Comment: if you don't have any error then you should rather show it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: see how you can format string on [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: A more descriptive question (with your input, desired output, the errors you faced) required

Comment: sorry new to forum how do i add this to code review instead of here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Drawing a tic tac toe board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269612/python-drawing-a-tic-tac-toe-board)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Brian's answer however you can set the value for each case within the .format method.

```
print("""
 {}|{}|{}
 -----
 {}|{}|{}
 -----
 {}|{}|{}
 """.format('x','x','o','o','o','x','o','x','o'))
```

will result with:

```
x|x|o
-----
o|o|x
-----
o|x|o
```

Each {} will be replaced by an argument of the .format method; in order.
Check [this link](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

```py
print("""
   |   |
------------
   |   |
------------
   |   |
""")
```

will result in a board like this:

```
   |   |
------------
   |   |
------------
   |   |
```